# Create asynchronous report in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I have an ASP.Net MVC web application where users should be able to create Excel reports. Some reports will take about 15 minutes to create. Therefore, I want to create these Excel files asynchronously and send them via email when they are ready.

Once the user has posted the form with the request to create Excel file, the user should get an answer that says "Mail with attached Excel file will be sent to you in about 15 minutes."

How do you do this?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit broad question, but for nice threading in .NET 4 you can use [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx).

You can create a plain Action in the Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExcelReport(ReportModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ReportService reportCreator = new ReportService(); // or whatever class you use for that
        Task.Factory.StartNew( () => reportCreator.GenerateReport(model)); 
        //redirect somewhere or return a plain view with your message
        return View("ConfirmationMessage");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Of course you have to mail it at the end of the generation in the GenerateReport or go even deeper and fire another Task from the GenerateReport method.

This is done all server side, if you want to have a popup, you'd have to use e.g. jQuery to intercept form submit, pass the model to a function of your choice where you fire the Task and use a popup from jQueryUI for the message. But that's a matter of preference. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with background work in ASP.NET is that ASP.NET can destroy the AppDomain and create a new one at any time ( recycling ). If you have work running on threads that the runtime doesn't know about, they will be destroyed too.

The normal solution is to have a separate Windows Service process that is responsible for doing the background work. Because this is a different process, it is not under control of ASP.NET.

So, your web app posts a request to do some work to the Service before the web response completes. This communication is normally using WCF hosted in the Service.

Comment: Thanks! I have now used Task.Factory.StartNew(...) and it works as long as the AppDomain isn't destroyed. I will try to implement it the correct way using WCF service when I have more time.